# How to return an array from rxjs observable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs

I've started with simply pulling in an array and mapping over the values, setting to state and then displaying on screen using conventional react and javascript methods

Now I want to rebuild this with rxjs

```
{
    "countriesList": [
        {
            "name": "Australia"
        },
        {
            "name": "Austria"
        },
        {
            "name": "Beligum"
        },
        {
            "name": "Belize"
        },
        {
            "name": "Brazil"
        },
        {
            "name": "Cameroon"
        },
        {
            "name": "Denmark"
        }
    ]
}


const countries$ = of(countriesList) // this returns the array above
```

but then I want to filter this list when I start typing values. typically I would build a function, and then filter based on the input. but struggling to replicate this with rxjs

I've tried the following and keep getting `countries.map` is not a function

```
return countries$.subscribe((countries) => countries)
```

I also tried this:

```
countries$.pipe(map((country) => country.filter((ctry) => ctry.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(e.target.value))))
```

whereby I want to map then filter and return the values that start with the letters typed in

not really getting the hang of this

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok for starters I am trying to learn `rxjs` lately so I hope my example will help you understand the differences between `of` and `from`.

Also it would be nice to review the [of](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of) and [from](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/from) "creators".

```
const { from, of, pipe } = rxjs;
const { map, filter } = rxjs.operators;

console.clear();

const countries = [
        {
            "name": "Australia"
        },
        {
            "name": "Austria"
        },
        {
            "name": "Beligum"
        },
        {
            "name": "Belize"
        },
        {
            "name": "Brazil"
        },
        {
            "name": "Cameroon"
        },
        {
            "name": "Denmark"
        }
    ];

const countriesFrom$ = from(countries);
const countriesOf$ = of(countries);

console.log("----stream from----")
countriesFrom$.subscribe(val => console.log(val));

console.log("----stream of----")
countriesOf$.subscribe(val => console.log(val));

const countries$ = from(countries);

console.log('----filtering----');

countries$.pipe(
  filter(country => country && country.name && country.name.startsWith('A')),
  map(console.log)
).subscribe()
```

basically `of` unlike `from`, it does not do any flattening and emits each argument in whole as a separate next notification